# firebase "where no-in" adding current value to the array

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I asking myself if we could use this :

```
arrayId: Array<string> = [];
[...]
findAllContacts(): Observable<Message[]> {
    return this.db.collection('messages', ref => {
      return ref
        .where("clientId", "==", this.clientId)
        .where("contactProId", "not-in", this.arrayId)
    }).valueChanges({ isField: 'id' }) as Observable<Message[]>;
  }
```

but where `arrayId` could be changed during the search. By adding the current contactProId to not fetch anymore for this contactProId?
Anyone have any idea how we could do this?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries in Firestore are immutable, so there's no way the query will pick up changes to `this.arrayId` once you've constructed it.

You will have to start a new query for the new condition. If you [enable offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence), the new query will be able to reuse most of the data that has already been read from the local cache.